# What purpose does the 'Take Picture' function serve in the Far Cry 3 Camera?

Tags: far-cry-3

The camera in Far Cry 3 is useful for tagging enemies from a distance but also includes the ability to take pictures.  This does not seem to do anything useful when used on animals or enemies.  Is there a purpose?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it turns out, the Take Picture functionality is ONLY used in missions (Thanks Paralytic) ([Source:](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/632849-far-cry-3/64784649)).

Comment: you should also add that some missions require you to take pictures of things

Comment: @Paralytic - I assumed jhappoldt was only looking for the 'idle' uses of the camera, but you're right, added.

Comment: In the PC, do you know the directory where the screenshot, camera-taken pictures in Far Cry 3 are located?

Comment: Hmm, an article I read ages back said you could, but according to [this](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/632849-far-cry-3/64784649), it can't actually take screenshots. What a bummer. I always assumed that was the point, but never bothered to try it in game

Answer (score 0):

One of the screen tips while the levels load says that you can use it to track enemies.

Take a picture of them and you will see an indicator hover over their heads so you can more easily track multiple enemies.

Comment: You don't need to take a picture for that, the camera will automatically mark enemies and animals as soon as they are in view.